# gradle : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, gradle, android-room

i'm trying to build a project using Room database , but i'm getting the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/room/compiler/processing/XProcessingStep
        at androidx.room.RoomProcessor.initSteps(RoomProcessor.kt:43)
        at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.init(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.init(incrementalProcessors.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.init(annotationProcessing.kt:156)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:500)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:597)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:690)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:79)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.room.compiler.processing.XProcessingStep
        ... 40 more
```

any idea please ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

if you use multi module, upgrade room from 2.3.0 to 2.4.0-beta02. It should fix the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).